# Adding to static table at compile time in Java

Tags: java

Sorry for the stupid java question, I'm not a Java programmer but I'm doing some maintance on larger codebase.

I want to have a table of strings that the entries are added during compile time. So that as classes are added to the system and would later be dynamically loaded. That table would allow me to emit the class names in documentation.

For example, if I have a subclass that represent a data sources, I'd like to be able to on the CLI say, "--help source" and have the table printed to stdout.

Comment: Do you know of [the service loader API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)? What do you mean by a "table"? A database table? You may want to use a build tool and exploit its hooks or extensions to do that. But this is all looking like a code smell.

Comment: How do you define "data sources"?

Comment: @ernest_k A I think he wants to get an ordenary two colmun table which list the class name and the data.

Comment: Perhaps something like https://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/processing-code.html might help?

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. The database/source is secondary. What I want to be able to do is allow the codebase to have new subclasses added and allow that functionality to be called via the command line. Presenting what subclasses are linked into any particular version would be useful. Doing this via reflection is the fastest for my code base, rather than asking the developers to update the cli help text.